# Body cut off at bottom when using twitter bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am attempting to make a simple site with twitter bootstrap and a sticky footer.  However, when I initialize the responsive css the body is cut off at the bottom of the page.  I have read the answer is to setup the body attributes before the responsive css is initialized like so:

```
@import url("bootstrap.min.css");


body {
  padding: 80px 0px 80px;
  height: 100%;
  background: #E3A822;
}

@import url("bootstrap-responsive.min.css");
```

I have done this on a rails application before and it worked fine.  However, I'm building a very simple page now and it is not working.  Everything after the body callout is ignored.  I have read that this is actually improper css.  My question is how do I define the body attribute before I import the responsive css but after I import the core bootstrap.

Comment: "height:100%" restricts it to the size of its container, try "height:auto" instead.

Comment: So simple!  Thank you!  So there actually is no need to specify the body attributes before I import the responsive css?

Comment: Doesn't the height default to auto?  Just remove the height altogether.